# Where can I find a good introduction or documentation on Objective-C blocks?

Tags: objective-c, ios, closures, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to use blocks in Objective-C.  I've worked through [this tutorial](http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/), but I would like to know more about blocks.

Where should I look for better documentation or tutorials on Objective-C blocks and their usage?

Comment: Apple's documentation is always a good start: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/

Comment: That's a very good article. It even provides links for further study, including one to Apple's own documentation. What more do you want?

Comment: Mike Ash wrote many great articles on blocks, e.g. http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html . Also see other posts by him.

Comment: Thanks guys for the response. I just wanted to understand the concepts of blocks in different ways possible. I would go through apple's documentation.

Comment: This post at Cocoa with Love is also good. http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/how-blocks-are-implemented-and.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Collecting the answers from the comments (and turning this answer community wiki for fairness) so we have an answer to this question:

**Apple's official documentation**

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/

**Mike Ash**

http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html

**Cocoa With Love**

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/how-blocks-are-implemented-and.html